# Ask a javascript paste event to get image data

Tags: javascript, html

I need to paste an image — from the desktop — into an editable `<div>` element.

Normally, intercepting the image and pasting it into the div can get the image data of base64; but you can't get a picture file from the desktop to the `<div>`.

Example 1:

1. Screenshot software,
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>,
3. paste display image into `<div>` (This way you can get base64 image data.)

Example 2:

1. Find the `.jpg` suffix name of the picture on the desktop,
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>,
3. paste display picture into the `<div>` (this way you *cannot* get base64 image data)

```js
function getPasteImgData(e) {
  if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.items) {
    ele = e.clipboardData.items;
    for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; ++i) {
      if (ele[i].kind == 'file' && ele[i].type.indexOf('image/') !== -1) {
        var blob = ele[i].getAsFile();
        console.log(blob);
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

```css
#pasteDiv {
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="pasteDiv" contenteditable="true" onpaste="getPasteImgData(event);"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to copy the image file and get the data of the image, just like CKEditor.

Comment: I've just edited your question, to improve the presentation (in my opinion); this is subjective and it's *your* question. So please check the edit and adjust to your taste (particularly the numbered lists of steps, where I changed "page" to "paste," which I think you meant but it was a guess).